# How to run the same test multiple times in order to measure flakyness

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have some tests that seem to be very flaky.

As part of the debugging process, I want to be able to run the same test multiple times through a TestCafe framework.

Any ideas about how to execute the same test multiple times and getting a report with some statistics on pass\failures?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

TestCafe has a special test run mode ([quarantinemode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html#quarantinemode)) that reruns failed tests and marks them as unstable in a test execution report. See more information about the 'Quarantine mode' [here](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#quarantine-mode).

Comment: I would like to run the same test even if it pass so I get true statistics about the percentage it fail compare to it pass

Answer (score 4):

You can run the test in a loop for debugging purposes. For example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    test(`test ${i}`, async t => {
        // ...
    });
}
```